# xcode weird behaviour after commit on single file

Tags: xcode, git

Using xcode gui to create a commit on a single file, i found myself looking at something unexpected, meaning the file reverted to previous commit or so it appears.
If I select the view by history, I can see on the left the local revision and on the right the previous commit.
BUT if i select local revision on the right, i can see ALL my changes, which obviously differ from the local revision appearing on the left.

Can someone explain to me what the hell is going on, and especially what am i suppose to do now?
Are those changes really commited?
Should i backup everything just in case?
A little help would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

Seems that restarting xcode fixed the issue, but i would like very much to understand what happened, still